# What is the equivalent of g_param_spec_boxed() in Vala?

Tags: vala

What is the equivalent of [g_param_spec_boxed()](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Standard-Parameter-and-Value-Types.html#g-param-spec-boxed) in Vala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions are not bound. It wouldn't be a big deal to bind them, so you can request them by reporting a bug.
Anyway, unless you're doing something at run-time, you should use Vala properties such as:

```
public class Foo {
    public YourStruct your_struct { get; set; }
}
```

Which will create a property named your_struct for the boxed type YourStruct.